# How long does it take for zinc oxide powder and heinz vinegar to fully react into zinc acetate at a 1:2 ratio of zinc:heinz vinegar?

Tags: metal, transition-metals, organometallic-compounds, salt

How long should I leave a solution of zinc oxide powder and heinz vinegar in order for it to react as completely as possible? The solution is 1(zinc oxide powder):2(heinz vinegar) in a glass flask. How much is this process increased by heat (say 50 deg C)? Without heat, should I cover the flask to prevent the acetic acid from evaporation while it reacts?

Comment: Heinz vinegar is not a chemical substance to determine the ratio. If the vinegar contained 60 g acetic acid/L (about 6%), than you need minimally 2 L of vinegar for about 81 g of zinc oxide, but little excess would be needed.

Comment: So the short answer to the title question is: It would never fully react.

Comment: @Poutnik thank you so much for this response! How long would it take for the reaction to occur at room temp vs. gentle heat/stovetop?

Comment: And also just for future reference, what kind of calculation is done to determine how long these kind of reactions take? I now know you can use stoichiometry to figure out the ratios (lol), so what's the kind for duration as a function of temp?

Comment: Heterogenous reactions have too many unknown variables, so nothing beats empirical data. As a rule of thumb, reaction rates increase typically 2-4 times per 10 °C increase.

Answer (score 1):

You might be far better off to react vinegar with *zinc carbonate*, yielding zinc acetate and CO2.

Zinc carbonate is much more soluble in water, no need for heating, just stir a bit.

Comment: Thanks for this I will definitely do that next time - but zinc oxide is what I have on hand....

Comment: @tomatopies you can try it with ZnO.  Just leave it overnight.  Beware acetic acid fumes if you reflux with heat (do it in a hood).  If no luck consider going to ZnCl with HCl to get it into solution, then make the carbonate with baking soda.